# ffmpeg on android on a video http

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have to create such a file, on android from a video that is on http:
[image]

So I have the following questions:

1. Is there any way to use ffmpeg on android?
2. How much does it cost me
   to create this file? Consider that we do not use the wifi connection
   and use the data connection, how much would it cost me in megabite?

Assuming that the video is lasting 2 hours.

Comment: just watching 2 video hours on a phones 4G connection is expensive. I'd reconsider the requirement to consume and demux a long video on the phone. Consider doing ffmpeg-2-photos on a server then accessing the output of that op from the phone.

Comment: @RobertRowntree: We assume that the video lasts 2 hours, but is only seen for a few minutes using the data connection.
I can not use a server, because the video is played at a particular url.
Insense that an url is generated for that particular ip connection.
The video server can not give me a series of previews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to create - whether it is combining multiple images into a video or combining multiple videos into a single grid, but as a quick note either way if you can do it server side you will have the luxury of more processing power, less battery usage concerns and possibly less bandwidth issues also.

Assuming you do want to do it on Android, then one way to use ffmpeg which I have found worked well is to use a wrapper program. One well supported example is here:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

There may be newer ones now also.

Comment: I can not use a server, because the video is played at a particular url. Insense that an url is generated for that particular ip connection. The video server can not give me a series of previews. You say you used: FFmpeg-Android-Java?

Comment: Actually I built my own ffmpeg wrapper, but I wished I had used a well supported one when I was done - this was some time ago. It worked well although there are quite a few tricks if you are building it yourself as command line ffmpeg was not intended to be used in a wrapper. That's why I would go with the best supported one you can find - it should be quicker overall.